# Unity5: How to draw texture additive to rendertexture?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a RenderTexture on which I want to draw with a "brush" texture. It's a height-map, so watherver is in the brush should be added to the value of the RenderTexture.

Drawing a texture to a rendertexture isn't too hard:

```
RenderTexture.active = _heightMap; //the render texture to be drawn to
Rect screenRect = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
Graphics.DrawTexture(screenRect, _brush, _addBrushMaterial);
```

I think I now need a material that will add the color of the brush to me texture ("_addBrushMaterial"). However I can't find how to make it so it adds it's color. At the moment it's fragment shader simply sets the color, so that's no good, it should add it:

```
float4 frag (v2f_img i) : SV_Target
{
    float4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
    return col * _Scale;
}
```

The documentation about this seems very limited, so any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found something that works. All I had to do was add "Blend One One".

I now use the following shader:

```
Properties
{
    _MainTex ("Brush", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Scale("Scaling factor", Float) = 1.0
}
SubShader
{
    // No culling or depth
    Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

    Pass
    {
        Blend One One

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert_img
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float _Scale;

        float4 frag(v2f_img i) : SV_Target
        {
            return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _Scale;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```